# How to automatically substitute the type of the returned template с++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, metaprogramming, sfinae

Is it possible in c++ to automatically substitute a data type from a template return value, without specifying a specific type in parentheses?

I am practicing metaprogramming and tried to execute the following code. To which I received the compilation error specified below.

```cpp
template <typename T>
T func(int value) {
    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>)
        return (float)value;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,std::string>)
        return std::to_string(value);
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>)
        return value;
}

int main() {
    auto o1 = func<int>(6); //Ok int 6
    std::string o2 = func(6); // CE
}
```

Comment: template parameter deduction can be performed only based on arguments. If template parameter is not used to define argument type it have to be stated explicitly.

Comment: There is workaround for it, but you will not like it.

Comment: Narrowly, you can provide a default value for `T`. `template <typename T = int>` would mean that `func(6)` is the same as `func<int>(6)`. But I'm not really sure what you want here, your function is very strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return a class with template conversion operator

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

struct Impl {
  int value;
  template<class R>
  operator R() const {
    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<R>)
      return (float)value;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<R, std::string>)
      return std::to_string(value);
    else if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<R>)
      return value;
  };
};

auto func(int value) {
  return Impl{value};
}

int main() {
  std::string s = func(1); // "1"
  float f = func(2);       // 2.0
  int i = func(3);         // 3
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b3zTqrn4d)

Comment: I've just wrote similar thing :) https://godbolt.org/z/vWsfnMqGo